# Lost sudo/su on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: sudo, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sudoers

I have an Amazon EC2 instance. I can login just fine, but neither "su" 
nor "sudo" work now (they worked fine previously):

- "su" requests a password, but I login using ssh keys, and I don't 
  think the root user even *has* a password.
- "sudo `<anything>`" does this:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 222, should be 0 
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I probably did "chown ec2-user /etc/sudoers" (or, more likely "chown 
-R ec2-user /etc" because I was sick of rsync failing), so this is my 
fault.

How do I recover? I stopped the instance and tried the "View/Change 
User Data" option on the AWS EC2 console, but this didn't help.

EDIT: I realize I could kill this instance and create a new one, but was hoping to avoid something that extreme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that kind of situation I think you should be able to use a second instance to fix the problem:

- Detach the EBS disk containing the broken system
- Create another EC2 instance
- Attach & mount the disk to the new instance
- Fix the permissions
- Umount, detach & reattach to the original instance

Answer (score 5):

1. Stop your current instance
2. Detach Existing Volume
3. Create a new Volume
4. Attach new volume to your instance as "/dev/xvda"
5. Start your instance
6. Attach the old volume (one which has sudo privilege issue) back to the instance while it is running as "/dev/sdf"
7. Login to your instance using putty
8. Use the `lsblk` command to view your available disk devices and their mount points (if applicable) to help you determine the correct device name to use.

   ```
     ec2-user ~$ lsblk
     NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
     xvdf 202:80 0 100G 0 disk
     xvda1 202:1 0 8G 0 disk /
   ```

The output of lsblk removes the /dev/ prefix from full device paths. In this example, `/dev/xvda1` is mounted as the root device (note the MOUNTPOINT is listed as /, the root of the Linux file system hierarchy), and `/dev/xvdf` is attached, but it has not been mounted yet.

9. Use the following command to create a mount point directory for the volume. The mount point is where the volume is located in the file system tree and where you read and write files to after you mount the volume. Substitute a location for mount_point, such as /data.

   ```
   sudo su
   cd /mnt
   mkdir other
   mount /dev/xvdf other
   cd /
   chown -R root:root /mnt/other/etc/
   exit
   ```
10. Go back to AWS and stop the instance
11. Detach both the volumes and re-attach old (now fixed) volume as /dev/xvda
12. Start your instance and now your permissions should be back to what it was

Comment: Totally worked, but I had to reattach as /dev/sda1, not /dev/xvda.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and because it was so difficult I made a video to explain the solution. This is pretty much the same thing as Rekee's solution in the form of a video tutorial.

http://youtu.be/gh5CDtRX7Ho

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've answered this yourself...

> I probably did "chown ec2-user /etc/sudoers" (or, more likely "chown
>   -R ec2-user /etc" because I was sick of rsync failing), so this is my fault.

Either way, I don't think you can resolve this without gaining a root shell. (I'm unsure what recovery methods are possible on ec2?)

If you did indeed recursively chown /etc then I think rebuilding the server is the best way to go.